# Custom webpack config with next.js and next-fonts in a monorepo with @expo/vector-icons

Tags: webpack, next.js, monorepo

I am trying to use [solito](https://github.com/nandorojo/solito) to use a monorepo with React Native and Next.js.

I successfully created a brand new project.
My next step is to add a UI library called `react-native-paper`. Looks good so far on the React Native

**My problem: I need to setup a custom webpack config on `/next.config.js` to handle `.ttf` files, but I have no idea how**

That's what I have done, but it's stuck on an infinite loop.

```js
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    withTM,
    [
      withFonts,  <------ seams this custom config is not happy
      {
        enableSvg: true,
        webpack(config, options) {
          return config
        },
      },
    ],
    [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
  ],
  nextConfig
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I night I revisited my code and [simply removed the `webpack` custom config](https://github.com/flexbox/react-native-nextjs-monorepo/pull/1) and it's working.

```js
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [withTM, withFonts, [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }]],
  nextConfig
)
```